# Rails : record not save from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, record

I have a simple form using stripe checkout for payment as following :

```
<%= form_for Order.new do |f| %>
  <!-- Price -->                
  <% ["2465"].each do |amount| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= amount %>" />
  <% end %>
  <!-- Description -->  
  <% ["A product"].each do |description| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="<%= description %>" />
  <% end %>
  <!-- variable string -->
  <%= f.text_field :test %>
  <!-- Stripe script -->  
  <script 
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-panel-label="Payer {{amount}}"
    data-label="Payer 24,65€"
    data-billing-address="true"
    data-shipping-address="true"
    data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>">
  </script>
<% end %>
```

As you can see I have a field that the user can populate before launching the stripe pop-up for payment.

```
  <!-- variable string -->
  <%= f.text_field :test %>
```

The thing is that it's always returning nil in the database, whatever the user put.

I am trying to fetch the value from my **orders_controller.rb** as following :

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new 
    charge_error = nil 

    # Amount in cents
    if @order.valid? 
    # some stripe set up goes here...
    @order.description = params[:description]
    @order.amount = params[:amount]
    @order.test = params[:test]
    end
  end
```

From the console, the string is filled in parameters, but always return empty inside the records :

Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order"=>{"test"=>"VALUE ENTERED"}

> Order.last
> #< Order id: 74, test: nil>

Thanks

EDIT1:
full trace of record once saved :

```
 => #<Order id: 82, name: "jérémy zaccherini", created_at: "2017-04-28 12:08:41", updated_at: "2017-04-28 12:08:41", card_token: "tok_1ADXtnA5xCR7Wb7xlUyLKfIN", email: "zacch@gmail.com", address_line1: "Residence feuch, 75004 PARIS", address_zip: "75004", address_country: "France", address_city: "PARIS", description: "MpyProduct", amount: "2465", status: "Non traitée", test: nil>
```

EDIT SOLUTION :

Re read the [ruby doc about form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html), the solution was to use a form helper like this in my form :

```
<!-- variable string -->
  <%= text_area_tag(:test) %>
```

This way I am able to retrieve user's value entered from my controller :

```
@order.test = params[:test]
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why are you doing `["2465"].each do |amount|` to create a single field?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the order

```
def create
  @order = Order.new 
  charge_error = nil 

  # Amount in cents
  if @order.valid? 
    # some stripe set up goes here...
    @order.description = params[:description]
    @order.amount = params[:amount]
    @order.test = params[:test]
  end
  @order.save
end
```

Save the order with `@order.save` after setting the values

Comment: Well, I was actually saving the order a little bit below these lines of code.

See my edit for the complete trace of the saved record. Test value for records is still nil.

Comment: Solved it with form helpers. See updated question. Thanks !